# Youtube API not ready sometimes

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

I'm trying to include a youtube vid using their API. However, sometimes (really random. Most times it works) I get an error when I click my play button:

```
Cannot read property 'playVideo' of undefined
```

This is how I included the API:

```js
var player;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('video-intro', {
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        videoId: '<id>',
        playerVars: {
            color: 'white',
            controls: 0,
            showinfo: 0
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#play-intro').click(function() {
       player.playVideo();
       $('#video-intro').addClass('showvid');
    });
});
```

```css
#video-intro {
  display: none;
  &.showvid {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="video-intro"></div>
  <a id="play-intro">Play</a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call events to start the player. And you can't play video before its loading. that't why you are getting undefined error. i have added events and functions check now. Better example can be found here [enter link description here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)

```js
var player;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('video-intro', {
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        videoId: 'TZbUi0FP5AM', //T7Kmc7T-pjY (old, short)
        playerVars: {
            color: 'white',
            controls: 0,
            showinfo: 0
        },
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
    });
    
}
 function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
      }
 var done = false;
 function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
         setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
          done = true;
       }
 }
 function stopVideo() {
        player.stopVideo();
 }      
      
      
      
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#play-intro').click(function() {
       onYouTubeIframeAPIReady();
      
       $('#video-intro').addClass('showvid');
    });
});
```

```css
#video-intro {
  display: none;
  &.showvid {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
  <script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="video-intro"></div>
  <a id="play-intro">Play</a>
</body>
```

Comment: Hmm, but now my video starts playing in the background already (I hear the sound, for 6 seconds). I only want it to play when I press the button. Also, my 'close/stop' button doesn't work anymore. My close button calls these functions: player.pauseVideo(); player.seekTo(0);. But it gives errors that stopVideo and pauseVideo don't exist.

Comment: You mean you want player paly/pause button or you need external button to play? @Cake

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not working in SO Snippet. Try to show the element first (Your CSS is not working) then call `player.playVideo()` otherwise it will give error as shown in your question.

Use the below CSS to show your Iframe,

```
#video-intro {
  display: none;
}
#video-intro.showvid {
  display: block !important;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="video-intro"></div>
<a id="play-intro">Play</a>
<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
<script>
  var player;

  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('video-intro', {
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      videoId: 'TZbUi0FP5AM', //T7Kmc7T-pjY (old, short)
      playerVars: {
        color: 'white',
        controls: 0,
        showinfo: 0
      }
    });
  }
  document.getElementById("play-intro").addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById('video-intro').className = 'showvid';
    player.playVideo();
  });
</script>
```

**[Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/rohankumar1524/5xw3hL69/)**