# Chrome Seems to Break Youtube Embed API?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a site that uses javascript to add timestamp abilities to embedded youtube videos. The script works on every browser except for Google Chrome. I've included a code snippet below for reference.

```
PXX.media = new YT.Player('pxx-youtube-player', {
    events: {
        onReady: PXX.doYoutubeSkip
    }
});
```

Once the JS is loaded, I can type `PXX.media.playVideo()` in the console in Firefox (as referenced in https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) and the video does start to play. It works in Internet Explorer and Safari as well.

Chrome however returns

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'playVideo' of undefined at
>   :1:11"

I'm really not sure what is causing the same code that works everywhere else to come back undefined on Chrome? Anyone know what I'm missing? I've been trying to find the solution for a few hours no with no luck.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: sound like the issue at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44884461/youtube-api-not-ready-sometimes)

Comment: The error message says **PXX.media** is undefined, which means your code didn't run or it ran in the wrong execution context. Without [MCVE](/help/mcve) can't help further. Use Chrome's devtools to debug the code.